# Buffer Overflow :Fortify :C++

Tags: c++, fortify

I am working on some of the Buffer Overflow issues pointed by Fortify and not able to figure out the problem.

The intention here is to remove the last inserted charahter in _inbuf

```
char *_inbuf = inbuf;

while (rflag) {
      strncpy(&_inbuf[actlen-1], &_delim, sizeof(_delim)+1);
      //_inbuf[actlen-1]=_delim;
      _inbuf += actlen;
      maxlen -= actlen;
      rflag = ReadLine(_inbuf, maxlen, actlen); //This actually calls istream::getline() 
   }

_inbuf[actlen-1]=0;
```

The last line complains of the "Buffer Overflow" issue.

Comment: How large is the buffer? What is `_delim`? Does `ReadLine` modify `actlen`?

Comment: buffer is allocated with 33k bytes. _delim here is a '\n'. Yes, ReadLine updates actlen every time with number of characters read

Comment: Then your `strncpy` is undefined since reading more than `sizeof(_delim)` bytes beyond `&_delim` is undefined  (and `&delim` does not point to a zero-terminated array so `strncpy` isn't a good choice). Why don't you just `_inbuf[actlen-1] = _delim;`?

Comment: You are right. I changed it because I was getting the same issue as the last line.